# How to create contingency table with multiple criteria subpopulation from weighted data using svyby in the survey package?

Tags: r, survey, contingency

I am working with a large federal dataset with thousands of observations and thousands of variables. Replicate weights are provided. I am using the "survey" package in R to apply these weights:

```
els.weighted=svrepdesign(data=els, repweights = ~els$F3F1PNLWT,
combined.weights = TRUE).
```

I am interested in some categorical descriptive characteristics of a subset of the population, such as family living arrangements. I want to get these sorted out into a contingency table that shows frequency. I would like to sort people based on four variables (none of which are binary, but all of which are numeric) This is what I would like to get:

[image: desired output here].

The blank boxes are where the cross-tabulation/frequency counts would show. (I only put in 3 columns beneath F1COMP for brevity's sake, but it has 9 outcomes – indexed 1-9)

```
My current code: svyby(~F1FCOMP, ~F1RTRCC +BYS33C +F1A10 +byurban, els.weighted, svytotal)
```

This code does sort the data, but it sorts every single combination, by default. I want them pared down to represent only specific subpopulations of each variable. I tried:

```
svyby(~F1FCOMP, ~F1RTRCC==2 |F1RTRCC==3 +BYS33C==1 +F1A10==2 | F1A10==3 +byurban==3, els.weighted, svytotal)
```

But got stopped:

```
Error: unexpected '==' in "svyby(~F1FCOMP, ~F1RTRCC==2 |F1RTRCC==3 +BYS33C=="
```

Additionally, my current version of the code tells me how many cases occur for each combination, This is a picture of what my current output looks like. There are hundreds more rows, 1 for each combination, when I keep scrolling down.

This is a picture of what my current output looks like. There are hundreds more rows, 1 for each combination, when I keep scrolling down

[image].

You can see in that picture that I only get one number for F1FCOMP per row – the number of cases who fit the specified combination – a specific subpopulation. I want to know more about that subpopulation. That is, F1COMP has nine different outcomes (indexed 1-9), and I want to see how many of each subpopulation fits into each of the 9 outcomes of F1COMP.

Comment: It's possible that this is a complete description of a problem, but given the fact that it seems rather complex, I'm guessing I would have difficulty coming up with a test case to run in R and wouldn't really know if my test case would match your problem even if I succeeded. So I'm passing on attempting any solution. You might get more effort on your behalf if you put in R code that constructed a realistic test case.

Comment: for `F1RTRCC==2 |F1RTRCC==3` you can put that statement in parentheses and it should work